# Sonarqube - avoiding catch generic Exception

Tags: java, sonarqube

Sonar complains when catching the generic type **Exception**, but sometimes we need to do some general exception handling for ALL (even not yet recognized) exception types. What is the solution to pass this sonar check?

Comment: Ignore the warning. https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+FAQ#JavaFAQ-HowtoremoveFalse-Positiveissues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are invoking a method which throws `Exception`, there is no need to catch `Exception`: catch the exceptions you know about, and the compiler will tell you when you have to start handling another one.

The problem with catching "not yet recognized" `Exception`s is that you lose the signal that you have to handle a new exception in a special way.

For example:

```
void someMethod() {
  // Do stuff.
}

void callIt() {
  try {
    someMethod();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

If `someMethod` is now changed so that it throws, say, an `InterruptedException`:

```
void someMethod() throws InterruptedException {
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  // Do stuff.
}
```

you aren't told by the compiler that you need to add handling for the `InterruptedException` in `callIt()`, so you will silently swallow interruptions, which may be a source of problems.

If, instead, you had caught `RuntimeException`, or `RuntimeException | IOException | OtherExceptionYouAlreadyKnowAbout`, the compiler would flag that you had to change your code to handle that `InterruptedException` as well; or, that you can't change the signature of `someMethod()`, and the checked exception has to be handled there.

Comment: Using RuntimeException could solve the problem, but I think RuntimeException is - to follow the idea of Sonar individual handling of exceptions - also generic. In my concrete case I'm using Jaxb to unmarshall a XML string. Compiler says me only about JAXBException, but now when the XML string contains something like &foo (without semicolon) in a value, the exception is com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException.

Comment: @Nader it is also generic, but it's an unchecked exception: you're not *really* meant to try to (or be able to) recover from it in a meaningful way, because it indicates a programming error. It's reasonable just to say "meh, a problem occurred; don't tear down the world, but there's nothing to be done". A checked exception, on the other hand, is meant to indicate something that you should be able to do something to recover from (e.g. retry, because I was only interrupted on this invocation, and it may succeed next time).

Comment: well explained! I was not aware of checked/unchecked. Thank you.

Comment: @Nader you may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation

Comment: What if I want to log the exception and rethrow it?